# NHibernate Mapping Exception: Part of file path incorrect

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, razor, nhibernate-mapping

I would like to use NHibernate in an MVC application I'm working on, and I'm having trouble with the configuration. I'm using a setup I found on this [blog](http://dotnetfever.com/using-nhibernate-with-asp-net-mvc-4/).

```
public class NHibernateHelper
{
    private static ISessionFactory _sessionFactory;

    private static ISessionFactory SessionFactory
    {
        get 
        {
            if (_sessionFactory == null)
            {
                var NHibernateConfig = new Configuration();
                NHibernateConfig.Configure(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"Models\NHibernate\hibernate.cfg.xml"));
                NHibernateConfig.AddDirectory(new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"Models\NHibernate\Mapping")));
                _sessionFactory = NHibernateConfig.BuildSessionFactory();
            }

            return _sessionFactory;
        }  
    }

    public static ISession OpenSession()
    {
        return SessionFactory.OpenSession();
    }
}
```

I've been fiddling a bit with the application trying to get the connection working, and now I'm getting an error at the following line:

```
NHibernateConfig.Configure(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"Models\NHibernate\hibernate.cfg.xml"));
```

The error is below.

`{"Could not find a part of the path 'C:\\Users\\%username%\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\Helpdesk4\\Helpdesk4\\Ticket\\Models\\NHibernate\\hibernate.cfg.xml'."}`

I can see clearly where the problem is. There is no "Ticket" directory. It should go `...Helpdesk4\\Helpdesk4\\Models\\...`. But I have no idea why the `MapPath` thinks that should be part of the path.

If it helps, here are some details from my `_Layout.cshtml` and `TicketController` files:

TicketController

```
    public ActionResult TicketLog()
    {
        IList<Ticket> lstTickets = _repository.getTickets();
        return View(lstTickets);
    }
```

Layout:

```
                 <nav>
                    <ul id="menu">
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Ticket Log", "TicketLog", "Ticket")</li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Server.MapPath uses a relative path from your request - so if your first request is to `/Tickets`, then `Server.MapPath(@"Models\NHibernate\hibernate.cfg.xml")` will resolve it relative to `/Tickets` - hence `/Tickets/Models/`etc...

Simply change it to `Server.MapPath(@"~\Models\NHibernate\hibernate.cfg.xml")` and it should find the config file - the `"~\"` tells it to map it from the root of the application